# A romantic riddle

Tags: riddle, word

This is my first ever riddle. Hopefully, it's not too obvious (or stupid) :-)

> When it breaks it doesn't hurt
>
> A symbol of a whole new birth
>
> One letter changed and a star's name
>
> Tomorrow the path will be the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it may be

> Dawn

When it breaks it doesn't hurt

> It doesn't hurt when dawn breaks (unless you're a vampire)

A symbol of a whole new birth

> A new day, a new life

One letter changed and a star's name

> Dawn -> Down. Add sun to get sundown, the continuation of the path described below. (Thanks to Will in the comments!)

Tomorrow the path will be the same.

> The sun follows the same path every day.

Comment: Ha! Was just typing this. Discarded.

Comment: If the third line refers to sundown then the riddle is sort of "cyclic" in a way...

Comment: Yes! We have a winner :)

Comment: @Will You are right :)

Comment: @Will Good thinking. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously not right, but:

> Amniotic sac

When it breaks it doesn't hurt

> When a woman's water breaks, it's not usually accompanied by pain

A symbol of a whole new birth

> But it does mean the baby is coming!

One letter changed and a stars name

> Obvious again.  Just change one I to an A, and rearrange the letters, you get "A MANIAC SCOT", so perhaps Gordon Ramsey...or really any other famous Scotsman

Tomorrow the path will be the same

> Well, perhaps not after childbirth...

Does tie in with the puzzle's title though!

Comment: Haha! Nice one :D

Answer (score 1):

> The Sun

When it breaks it doesn't hurt

> Sunbreak...

A symbol of a whole new birth

> That could mean all sorts of things, probably birth of a new day

One letter changed and a star's name

> Tricky one, threw me off because obviously "Sun" doesn't need any letters changed. There is a star named "San" though, at least according to this http://starnames.wikia.com/wiki/Stars_Beginning_with_S

Tomorrow the path will be the same.

> I certainly hope so!

Comment: You're sooo close, but that's not the word I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

> A heart

When it breaks it doesn't hurt:

> A broken heart doesn't hurt.. Physically anyway..

A symbol of a whole new birth:

> A heart is often used to represent lives in games, which signify a respawn, or a new 'birth'

One letter changed and a stars name:

> Not sure

Tomorrow the path will be the same:

> Not sure

Comment: Not even close, but I do really like the "whole new birth" explanation :D

Comment: Just an idea, for the letter change, "heart" takes the "h" and put it at the end, you get "earth" (not a star but ...)

Comment: @駑馬十駕 Yes, I did think of that, but as you mentioned, sadly not a star